# 7Zip Creating Empty Zip Files

Tags: vbscript, 7zip

I've coded this and the zipping logic is working but when the zip file is generated, it has no files on it even though the there are files in the source location.

`oFile` is the file referenced from the source location while `sDirectoryDestPath` is the directory location of the zip file. What do you think is the cause why it is not including the files in the zip?

Also, I don't want to append the directory part of the source to the `oFile` since it is copying the whole folder structure. I just need the file to be on the zip destination location.

```
Sub archiveFile(oFile)
  Dim wshshell, Command, zipFileName

  Set wshshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell") 

  WScript.Echo oFile.name

  If bArchive Then
      zipFileName = Year(oFile.DateLastModified) & Right("0" & Month(oFile.DateLastModified),2) & ".zip"

      Command = """D:\7ZIP\7za.exe"" a " & sDirectoryDestPath & "\" & zipFileName & " " & oFile.Name

      call wshshell.run(Command,0,true) 
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have `option explicit` turned on? Is the variable `sDirectoryDestPath` global? From what i can see it should be null since it is not declared

Comment: Is `oFile` located in the working directory? Replace `WScript.Echo oFile.Name` with `WScript.Echo oFile.Path & vbNewLine & wshshell.CurrentDirectory` to verify that.